# How do you say 头大 in English?

Tags: word-requests

> 英语太难了，学得我头大。

I just don't want to use "head exploding" which scares me.

Comment: Should be moved to ell.se, it's about English, not Chinese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

頭大 figuratively means *to be distressed/overwhelmed/worried*. In English, the equivalent word is the figurative *headache*.

> 英語太難了，學得我頭大
>
> *English is too difficult; studying it is (too overwhelming) / (giving me a headache)*

Answer (score 1):

头大 just means 'head is big' as in "头大没脑" (big head but no brain)

The common phrase is 头也大了 or 头都大了 . e.g. "英语太难了，学得我头也大了。"

The English expression "[make my head spin](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/make-one-s-head-spin)"  is a good counterpart of it

You can also simply say "my brain hurt"